# An equality in some extension field

Tags: extension-field

Let $L=K(\alpha)$ be a seperable field extension, end write $f \in K[X]$ for the minimal polynomial of the $\alpha$, let $\alpha_1, \cdots \alpha_n$ denote the roots. Prove the following equality:

$$
x^r \quad = \quad \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} \frac{f(x) \cdot \alpha_k^r}{(x-\alpha_k)f'(\alpha_k)}
$$

---

*What I tried myself*

First of all I rewrote $f$ and $f'$:

$$
f \ = \ \prod_{1\leq j \leq n} (X - \alpha_j) \quad \quad \text{and}
\quad \quad f' \ = \ \sum_{1\leq j \leq n} \prod_{i \neq j}(X-\alpha_i)
$$
Now this is what the big sum looks like if I am not mistaking:
$$
\sum_{1\leq k \leq n } \frac{\alpha_k^r \cdot \prod_{1\leq j \leq n} (X - \alpha_j)}{(x-\alpha_k)\sum_{1\leq j \leq n} \prod_{i \neq j}(\alpha_k-\alpha_i)
}
$$
Some of those products in the denominator might vanish, but that is all I can see. Can you give me a small hint to go on?

Comment: Is it $\;f(\alpha^r_k)\;$ or what does $\;f\cdot \alpha^r_k\;$ mean?

Comment: $f$ means $f(x)$

Comment: Start with $${f'(x)\over f(x)}=\sum{1\over x-\alpha_k}$$

Answer (score 2):

[Not quite a complete answer, but some progress]$${f'(x)\over f(x)}=\sum{1\over x-\alpha_j}$$ $${(x-\alpha_k)f'(x)\over f(x)}=1+\sum_{j\ne k}{x-\alpha_k\over x-\alpha_j}$$ Evaluating at $x=\alpha_k$, we get $${(x-\alpha_k)f'(x)\over f(x)}\Biggl|_{x=\alpha_k}=1$$ So the left and right sides of the equality agree at $x=\alpha_k$, $1\le k\le n$.

Comment: I understood everything you said aside from the last sentence

Comment: In the equality that you are trying to prove, if you let $x=\alpha_k$, then the left side is $\alpha_k^r$, and, by the calculation I gave, so is the right side.

Comment: mmm, does that mean that we need to show that $\sum_{j\neq k}\alpha_j \ = \ 0$, or am I mistaking?

Comment: I don't know why you think we need to show that sum is zero. Incidentally, you never mention $r<n$ in your question, but as Ewan pooints out the equation you want to prove is false without that assumption. That means my answer really is complete, since we get two polynomials of degree $r$ agreeing at more than $r$ places.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple and explained in the "Procedure" section on
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).

Consider the rational fraction $g(x)=\frac{x^r}{f(x)}$. Its degree is 
$r-n<0$, so it admits a partial fraction decomposition
of the form

$$
g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{c_k}{x-\alpha_k}
$$

where the $c_k$ are constants. Putting $h_j(x)=\prod_{k\neq j}(x-\alpha_k)$, we have

$$
\frac{x^r}{h_j(x)}=\frac{x-\alpha_j}{g(x)}=c_j+
\sum_{k\neq j}\frac{c_k(x-\alpha_j)}{x-\alpha_k}
$$

Setting $x=\alpha_j$ above, we obtain $c_j=\frac{\alpha_j^r}{h_j(\alpha_j)}=
\frac{\alpha_j^r}{f'(\alpha_j)}$.

Comment: Where do you get $r<n$? It's not in the statement of the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson When $r\geq n$, the identity becomes obviously false because the LHS and RHS have different degrees in $x$.